# Severe graphical glitches: Ubuntu - but not Windows! Dell G3 P89F002

Tags: dell

The issues occur **even during boot**: can only see the very top line of text output during start-up - the rest is a bit of glitchy horizontal lines and blank screen.

**BUT**: when booting into Windows there's no problem.

To be clear: even the **BIOS** screens and the boot text screen and GRUB are corrupted (except for the first few horizontal lines of pixels).  **However Windows, when selected in GRUB boots fine with no visual issues!**

That's what I don't get.

Once it got to GRUB, because nothing was visible except a few pixels width at the very top of the screen - the rest being glitched to invisibility - it was necessary to recall that Windows was the 3rd choice in the GRUB boot list and therefore hit down-arrow twice (blind) and then return.

Windows boots up beautifly with full graphics.

This started happening a few months ago. This is my son's machine so I'm not sure exactly the sequence when it started.

Really weird.  It seems to be a physical problem, but since there's no problem at all under Windows - it must be (at least partially) software.

The Ubuntu version is (I think!) 22.10 - maybe 22.04

By booting to Windows I see the graphics card is: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti.

A problem for, e.g., logging in to text terminals is that even for these (and as I've said, equally in the BIOS and GRUB) only the top few lines of pixels are visible. You can see it gets to the Ubuntu login screen because the top of the top-panel icons are visible. I'll keep trying various ways to get more information.

Comment: Details matter, esp. with issues that maybe related to kernel modules (aka *drivers*).  Ubuntu 22.10 used a different kernel to Ubuntu 22.04, and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS has kernel stack options; so please provide specific details.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/07/27/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2023/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: If it's a graphics problem, we would need to also know the exact make and model of the GPU hardware that is in use. As a rule of thumb if you are using an Nvidia GPU, then you should run `sudo apt update` and `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to install the proprietary Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  A problem I have right now is that I can't see the screen to be able to determine the exact Ubuntu version nor perform other actions like `apt` etc!

All that and I can run Windows fine!

I can't see the box via my router - not logged in and connected - so I can't `ssh` to it (not sure its got a `ssh` server running anyway).  I'll try attaching another monitor - doubt it will work.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific for us to provide specific help. One possibility (*depending on details you've not provided*) could be if you're using a LTS release (22.04) & HWE which changes kernel every ~six month; the last was when 22.04 became 22.04.3 with [this](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/08/11/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-released/) showing ISO release date, but installed system upgraded a week+ before then; if using HWE the kernel switched from 5.19 to 6.2 which can cause issues with some older hardware - but date [of change] & release will provide clues & you weren't specific.. one example

Comment: The last suggestion would however not apply if you were using 22.04 with the GA kernel stack but you've not yet provided clear release details; let alone more specific details (kernel stack). The switch from 5.19 (kernel from 22.10) was about the same time 22.10 reached EOL (*thus change to 23.04 kernel for HWE users of LTS*), but other causes could be at play; and your "*few months ago*" may trigger other events if you were more specific (*or release details were known!*)  I'd still expect you to be able to login using text terminal however in this example of possible issue.

Comment: Try to avoid commenting on your own question. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1490835/edit) instead to improve and clarify. Comments are how we help you improve the question until it is answerable. Then somebody will answer it.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 has reached end of life. Generally, newer versions of Ubuntu have better support for recent hardware. So, fresh install Ubuntu 23.10 (instead of 22.04). Afterwards, search for additional drivers in the menu,and install them.

Comment: I'd be (reasonably) happy to install 23.10 - but I can't see the text!  Normally I guess I'd say "okay - serious hardware fault - get a new computer".  **BUT** - Windows runs fine!  There's no (major) hardware problem surely.  But what's actually going on?

Comment: If you can see the `grub` selection screen at boot (what most/many of us use to select windows or Ubuntu) you can edit the entry and tell it to go to runlevel 1 (ie. text mode only), OR boot into recovery mode, OR alternatively booting normally as I commented before & switching to text terminal (ctrl+alt+F4 for example). I'd expect those to (as previously stated) provide clues as to what you're running, as until we know that, we're limited in what we can provide help with.